# Why does php artisan tinker redirect to my project directory?

Tags: php, laravel, debugging, laravel-artisan

I'm following this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=neSHAWdE44c&index=5&list=PLillGF-RfqbYhQsN5WMXy6VsDMKGadrJ-

At time 7:17, he uses `php artisan tinker`.

No matter what I do and/or try, upon running `php artisan tinker`, I then run `App\Post::count()` but all it does is redirect me back to the project directory.

I can't even do a simple `2 + 2` and see the output.  I just get redirected back to the project directory.

I'm using Laravel 5.7.25 if that's of any help.

I've looked all over SO but I'm trying to hang in there in terms of finding a solution.  Anybody have an idea what's causing this?

Example of what I mean:

```
name-MBP:lsapp name$ php artisan tinker
Psy Shell v0.9.9 (PHP 7.3.1 — cli) by Justin Hileman
>>> App\Post::count()
name-MBP:lsapp name$
```

Comment: does the tinker shell start up on running the command?

Comment: @olayemii yes it does, I've provided an example of what I'm talking about in my post.

Comment: do you have the App\Post model in your models?

Comment: @olayemii yeah I do, which makes it very strange why this isn't working

Comment: and no errors are thrown, that is strange

Comment: @olayemii yeah, I'm totally stumped.  I'm absolutely loving Laravel so far but this roadblock's really confusing me.

Comment: try creating a new laravel project, making auth so the user table is migrated, then try tinker on the user table i.e App\User

Comment: @olayemii I've done it before, I was doing another tutorial yesterday but ran into the exact same issue.

Comment: on what machine please?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188159/discussion-between-greyskies-and-olayemii).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is an issue with Psy Shell

Try creating a file named `config.php` at `~/.config/psysh` or `C:\Users\{USER}\AppData\Roaming\PsySH` (for windows) if not already there.
and put this as the content:

```
<?php
return [
  'usePcntl' => false,
];
```